# jQuery - Animation when page changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this website: http://www.heinesiebrand.nl/demo/

When the user is on the 'Home'-page, it sees a quote on top of the page. When you go to another page, that disappears. This now happens in a 'hard' transition, and i want to smooth that up using jQuery.

What I have so far is the following (note: I'm using Wordpress):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if (is_front_page()) { ?> 
             $("#animation").animate({ min-height: "140px" }, 500 );
     <?php } else { ?>
             $("#animation").animate({ min-height: "40px" }, 500 );
     <?php } ?> 
</script>
```

And the part to be animated:

```
<div class="contentwidth-footer" id="animation" style="min-height: 35px;">
    <?php if (is_front_page()) {
        display_tagline($post->ID); 
    } ?>
</div>
```

This doesn't work, so do you guys have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have a hard time doing what you want to do, because the links are regular links, and therefore cause a page reload. The effect you are looking for is created on pages that load content dynamically without reloads.

Comment: Alright thanks for your reply. Is there any way to do it, even with page reloads?

Comment: Using an unload event like squidbe suggested might make it a little better.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can come without "ajaxifying" the site is to fade out onunload:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  $("#animation").fadeOut();
});
```

EDIT: Actually, I don't think even that'll do what you want since it's executed *after* the page unloads -- might depend on the browser.

Comment: If you set animation onload then it will be always loaded when new page enter which is almost identical with when page unloads. To deal with initial first call you can with little but of server side code

Comment: Thanks guys, but i'm letting go of this idea because it jut wont work.